# CircleCI postman API automate testing not working

Tags: api, continuous-integration, postman, circleci, newman

I have this challenge with postman on circleci. my `config.yml` looks like this.

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  newman: postman/newman@0.0.2
jobs:
  build:
    newman-collection-run-env-timeout:
    executor: newman/postman-newman-docker
    steps:
      - checkout
      - newman/newman-run:
          collection: ./collection/new_test.postman_collection.json
          environment: ./env/New-lamp-staging.postman_environment.json
```

When I deployed to circleci, I got this error

```
❏ auth
↳ Register: 201 Created
  POST https://stagingauth.herokuapp.com/auth/accounts/register/ [415 Unsupported Media Type, 377B, 109ms]
  1. Status code is 201

↳ Register: 400 Bad Request
  POST https://stagingauth.herokuapp.com/auth/accounts/register/ [415 Unsupported Media Type, 377B, 19ms]
  2. Status code is 400
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: the error say the request body is not accepted by the server , debug in postman and see

Comment: @PDHide It works fine on postman. Circleci isn't recognising the request body as a json object.

Comment: That's the most recent version, it was created in 2019. if you have an updated version, please share.

Comment: try running that json file using newman npm module , may be you didn't export the collection and environment correctly

Comment: I did, it worked when I executed newman run @PDHide. Kindly check this gist for the result https://gist.github.com/bhadmus/d55576460920e210594c02e28859bcf8

Comment: see the answer both are different url

Answer (score 0):

You are having two different collection results , see the result file you have uploaded in git , the url is

```
https://stagingauth.herokuapp.com/auth/token/jwt
```

but in the circle CI the url is

```
https://stagingauth.herokuapp.com/auth/token
```

so you are trying to do post action on a wrong resource thats why get 415

Please make sure you are using correct collection and environment files and urls , and variable values are correct

Comment: `Login: 200 status
  POST https://stagingauth.herokuapp.com/auth/token/jwt [415 Unsupported Media Type, 377B, 70ms]
  1. Test To verify that the status code is 200`
It still returned the same error with the url

Comment: if you are using same collection and environment file why would azure and the other run point to different urls . There is some difference in the files please re verify